# How to show List items on Imageview in android?

Tags: android, imageview, android-viewpager

I have a List of Images path. I want to show all images of list in Imageview.
I am trying to show all images in view pager. For that i am creating a Imageview in view pager but not able to show images from list to imageview.
Can any one help me how can i achieve it.

Comment: why you don't use listView?

Comment: I am getting data from server which i am saving in List

Comment: ok, you can use array adapter to fill listView with data

Comment: if you can weit 5 minutes i can post i good sample of this implementation

Comment: @KostyaKhuta sure....y not??

Comment: ok, i am writing sample for you now

Comment: my post is below, check it please

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must to create your ArrayAdapter

```
   public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    ArrayList<String> pathToImage = null; 

    public NewsAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<String> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        PurchaseHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new PurchaseHolder();
            holder.iv=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.iv_news_status);//your image view id in item.xml
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (PurchaseHolder) row.getTag();
        }

   File imgFile = new  File(pathToImage.get(position);//your path to image
    if(imgFile.exists()){
     Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
     holder.iv=.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
     }
        return row;
    }

    private class PurchaseHolder {
        ImageView iv;

    }
}
```

in your Activity class make next

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(MyActivity.this, R.layout.item, arrayListOfImagePath);
myListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

How to use listview you can read in [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#listview_listviewexample) tutorial. But don't forget, you must use adapter wich i posted above